# Does Foreach Cache IEnumerable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Supposing that `SomeMethod` has signature

```
public IEnumerable<T> SomeMethod<T>();
```

is there any difference between

```
foreach (T tmp in SomeMethod<T>()) { ... }
```

and

```
IEnumerable<T> result = SomeMethod<T>();

foreach (T tmp in result) { ... }
```

In other words, will the results of `SomeMethod<T>` be cached on the first statement or will it be evaluated upon each iteration?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about C#.

`foreach` translates into something like this:

```
var enumerable = SomeMethod<T>(); // Or whatever is passed to foreach
var enumerator = enumerable.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
...
}
```

So, as `enumerable` is needed only once, there will be only one call to SomeMethod even if you put it directly into the `foreach` statement.

Comment: Slight quibble: There should be a "using" or "finally" block to ensure that if the enumerator implements IDisposable, it will get disposed.  There are many scenarios, especially involving iterators, where abandoned enumerators can cause severe problems.

Comment: @supercat: You're right but the example was only meant to show main concept of foreach, not to be used in production. The foreach itself will take care of disposing of the enumerator.

Comment: I understand that the code was designed to be illustrative, but a lot of people don't realize that code which creates an enumerator that implements IDisposable must, *for correctness*, ensure that Dispose gets called on the enumerator.  All that needs to happen to ensure correctness is to add a "using" block around the creation of the enumerator.

Comment: @supercat: Right; one could say himself, it's an IEnumerator, not IDisposable, why should I try to dispose? It's hard to see that if you get an interface, it could also be an object implementing any other interface. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: @supercat: Of course, "using" can't be used with the GetEnumerator which returns IEnumerator and the compiler would complain it can't tell if it's IDisposable too. So try-finally must be used with check if it really IS IDisposable.

Comment: The pattern I would recommend would be to use a "var" statement to get the enumerator, and then as the very next statement "using(enumerator as IDisposable)".  That should correctly handle the cases where enumerator is a type that's known at compile-time to implement IDisposable, a known sealed class that does not implement IDisposable, or a class that may or may not implement IDisposable (which needs to be tested at run-time).  One slight difference between that and the compiler's duck typing, for better or for worse, is that ...

Comment: ...if the return type of GetEnumerator is a class that does not implement IDisposable, the compiler's duck-typing won't generate code to check whether the run-time class of the object returned does; the above "Using" code would generate the check.  The check will slow things down, but would call IDisposable.Dispose in some cases the compiler's foreach code would miss.

Answer (score 1):

An enumerATOR is generally a different type of object from an enumerABLE.  Typically an enumerator will hold a reference to an enumerable object, along with some information about where it is in the process of enumeration.  The purpose of an enumerable object is not actually to supply a sequence of items, but rather to supply an enumerator which will in turn supply the sequence.

In both vb.net and C#, the foreach construct works by calling a GetEnumerator method once on the object and grabbing the object it returns, repeatedly calling MoveNext and Current on the object returned from GetEnumerator, and finally, if that object implements Dispose, calling Dispose on it.  Neither C# nor vb.net actually caches the enumerable object, but neither of them needs to use the object for any purpose after having called GetEnumerator on it once.  Both languages do hold onto the enumerator, but neither provides any means of doing anything with it other than the implied calls to MoveNext, Current, and Dispose.